# Implementation of ViewControllers in Swift project

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, uiviewcontroller, swift3

Im working on an app, where I want to have multiple exercises on separate viewControllers. As a part of the app, I want to make a Calendar feature (I know how to make a calendar), where I want to make some kind of diary - when you click on a day in the calendar, you can look through the list of those exercises and add them to that diary (day). Im not sure how to mark unique exercises(viewControllers), so I can use them for the calendar. Can you give me an idea what should I google/look for, where to start? I would be very thankful for a tip.

Comment: are you using event kit?

Comment: @SaurabhJain Yes, in the calendar feature

Comment: Can you explain your question more clearly?  What difficulty are you having with ViewControllers?

Comment: There should be a method when you select/click-on a particular date, do you have that method?